# MVC why are only anonymous types passed?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, anonymous-function

in a MVC application when you want to pass an id from the like this for example:

```
@if (Model.ImageData != null) { 
<div style="float:left; margin-right:20px">
    <img width="75" height="75" src="@Url.Action("GetImage",
    "Product", new {Model.ProductID})"/>
```

for a controller action method like this:

```
public FileContentResult GetImage(int productId)
{
    Product prod = repository.Products.FirstOrDefault
        (p => p.ProductID == productId);

    if (prod != null)
    {
        return File(prod.ImageData, prod.ImageMimeType);
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Why is it a must that it only works when I use anonymous new {Model.ProductID} ? When I try to pass the Model.ProductID as is given the Model is of type product, no Id is passed. How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an anonymous class like `new {Model.ProductID}`

Will actually create the object like so:

```
new {ProductId = Model.ProductID}
```

Which `Url.Action` will write out as `&ProductId=123`

The default Model binder is case insensitive and will be able to map this to `int productId` signature of your `GetImage` controller method.

Whereas `Model.ProductID` will just be an integer - this is typically only mapped to `id` in a default `MapRoute`.

Comment: Thank you, that cleared it up mostly, I would like to ask however, if there is a way to tell by the method signature that the anonymous type is one I must use for a method to work properly? For example, I also noticed that when adding routes through MapRoutes, the default properties are also created by anonymous types. Is it that whenever a method signature expects and object type that I should use anonymous types?

Comment: Hi Andrew - this is all to do with the HTTP query string (or POST data) generated by helper methods like `Url.Action`, as long as it produces a URL like `http://somesite/someapp/mycontroller/GetImage?productId=12345`. I'm not quite sure why MS fixated on using anon types in `MapRoutes` as this will obviously require reflection :)

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC uses property names in anonymous objects or keys in [RouteValueDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routevaluedictionary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instances to match the values to route parameters. For example, the default route in ASP.NET MVC has 3 route parameters:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

If you don't tell the framework which parameter to to use, it will create an ambiguity.